Angular with mermaid showing syntax error
I included a component, in a Angular 19 project, that shows a mermaid graph. Data to be handed to mermaid is retrieved from a backend. Graph is showing quite ok, but an error at the bottom is showing:

Syntax error in text mermaid version 11.4.1

The frame is the simplest
his.graphDefinition = `
flowchart TD
    a --> b`;

Here is the mermaid service I used to send out data:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import mermaid from 'mermaid';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
 })
 export class MermaidService {
    constructor() {
       mermaid.initialize({
        startOnLoad: false,
        theme: 'neutral',
       });
    }

    renderMermaid(content: string, elementId: string): void {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId) as Element;
    mermaid.render(elementId, content, element);
  }
}

Do you have any ideas about how to resolve this or at least debug it?
